# Why does url.Parse not populate URL.RawPath?

Tags: url, go, escaping

While with similar input, URL.RawQuery seems to be properly populated.

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/C9vFvAsxvW)

```
u, err := url.Parse("https://example.com/foo%2fbar")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(u.Path)
fmt.Println(u.RawPath)
fmt.Println(u.String(), "\n")

u, err = url.Parse("https://example.com/foo%25fbar?q=morefoo%25bar")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(u.Path)
fmt.Println(u.RawPath)
fmt.Println(u.RawQuery)
fmt.Println(u.String())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `URL.RawPath` is not the raw (escaped) path. It *may* be, but not always. It's just a *hint*. Its doc says:

```
RawPath    string // encoded path hint (Go 1.5 and later only; see EscapedPath method)
```

So when you need the escaped path, always use [`URL.EscapedPath()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.EscapedPath) and don't rely on the `URL.RawPath` field. Doc of `URL.EscapedPath()` says:

> EscapedPath returns u.RawPath **when it is a valid escaping of u.Path**.

This is your case. A raw path is invalid if it contains bytes that need escaping during URL encoding. Your path is such an example because it contains `%25` which is the URL escaped text of the percent symbol itself `'%'`, and percent symbols need to be escaped if part of URL paths.

Your first example contained `%2f` which is the URL escaped text of the  slash`'/'` which if present in a path does not need to be escaped (`'/'` is a valid character in paths and is treated as a separator).

See this example:

```
u, err = url.Parse("https://example.com/foo%25fbar?q=morefoo%25bar")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println("Path:       ", u.Path)
fmt.Println("RawPath:    ", u.RawPath)
fmt.Println("EscapedPath:", u.EscapedPath())
fmt.Println("RawQuery:   ", u.RawQuery)
fmt.Println("String:     ", u.String())
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YZC2Xq35Yt)):

```
Path:        /foo%fbar
RawPath:     
EscapedPath: /foo%25fbar
RawQuery:    q=morefoo%25bar
String:      https://example.com/foo%25fbar?q=morefoo%25bar
```

`RawPath` is the empty string (because `"/foo%25fbar"` is an invalid escaped path), but `EscapedPath()` returns you the original escaped path.

Comment: Doesn't a '%' need to be escaped in a query ? If not, why does url.Encode then change a '%' to '%25' in a query ?

Comment: @Sridhar Yes (if it is part of the param name or value). But the question here was: why does `%25` prevent `URL.RawPath` being filled, contrary to `%2f` which does not prevent it. And the answer is that because `%25` renders the path invalid based on the criteria listed in the answer, while `%2f` does not.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `func(*URL)EscapedPath()`

```
fmt.Println(u.EscapedPath()) //give you expected result
```

From package spec

> In general, code should call EscapedPath instead of reading u.RawPath
>   directly.

And from source comments

```
// RawPath is a hint as to the encoding of Path to use
// in url.EscapedPath. If that method already gets the
// right answer without RawPath, leave it empty.
// This will help make sure that people don't rely on it in general.
```